# Why isn't the image appearing when I navigate to a different page?

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I am trying to make a circle animation on my login page. However, when I navigate to my sign up page the circle disappears. I have no idea why it does that and have changed the durations already. I also have my deployment target set at iOS 17.

This is my code:

```
struct JoinPage: View{
    @State private var showSignup: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            LoginPage(showSignup: $showSignup)
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSignup) {
                    
                }
        }
        .overlay{
                CircleView()
                  .animation(.smooth(duration: 0.45, extraBounce: 0), value: showSignup)
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func CircleView() -> some View{
        Circle()
            .fill(.linearGradient(colors: [Color.green, .blue, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .frame(width: 200, height:200)
            .offset(x: showSignup ? 90 : -90, y:-90)
            .blur(radius: 15)
            .hSpacing(showSignup ? .trailing : .leading)
            .vSpacing(.top)
    }
}
```

This is where I manipulate showSignup from the login page:

```
 HStack(spacing: 6) {
                Text("Don't have an account?")
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                
                Button("Sign Up"){
                    showSignup.toggle()
                }
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .tint(Color.green)
            }
            .font(.callout)
            .hSpacing(.trailing)
        })
        .padding(.vertical, 15)
        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: ok sorry about that done

Comment: What you have provided is not a [mre]. You don't show you you're manipulating `showSignup`

Comment: Ok i just did that now thanks!

Comment: You should look at the link I provided and see how to format this to make a MRE